# Set Subtraction with Self Reference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there an example of a set $A$

Where we let $B = \{1,3,4,8\}$

And

$A - (B - A) = \{1,2,4,5,6,9,10,11\}$

I've been trying to get my head around it in the form of a Venn Diagram but it isn't going well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can approach it directly; this is a bit tedious, but it’s straightforward.

In this approach the first thing to realize is that $A\setminus(B\setminus A)$ is a subset of $A$, so $A$ must include all of the integers $1,2,4,5,6,9,10$ and $11$. Since $B=\{1,3,4,8\}$, this means that $B\setminus A$ can include **at most** $3$ and $8$: $1$ and $4$ are known to be in $A$ and therefore cannot be in $B\setminus A$. Thus, when we remove $B\setminus A$ from $A$, we’re removing **at most** the integers $3$ and $8$, which needn’t be there in the first place. This suggests that we should try letting $A=\{1,2,4,5,6,9,10,11\}$, the smallest set that it could possibly be; I’ll let you check that this works.

Notice that $A$ and $A\setminus(B\setminus A)$ ended up being the same set. This is not an accident, and a more insightful approach would have told us this in the first place. No matter what the set $B$ is, by definition the set $B\setminus A$ **does not contain any element of** $A$. Thus, when we remove this set from $A$, we’re not actually removing anything at all, and we necessarily get $A$ back. Thus, we could actually have answered the question without even knowing what $B$ was.

You can also this using a Venn diagram: no matter how you place $B$ in relation to $A$, the region $B\setminus A$ is disjoint from $A$, so subtracting it from $A$ removes nothing.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you very much. I hear you're a legend in these parts

Comment: @Gareth: You’re very welcome. I just have more time to spend than most!

Comment: It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For all sets $A$ and $B$, $A \setminus (B \setminus A) = A$. Therefore, let $A = \{1,2,4,5,6,9,10,11\}$.

Comment: Ah I see! I suppose trying to visualise it as a Venn Diagram was my undoing.

Comment: @GarethAllen-Stringer, to tackle the question with Venn diagrams, consider the operation of set difference in terms of the operations of intersection and complementation: $B \setminus A = B \cap A^{\complement}$. In case you revisit this question at a later time, I will upload an image of the Venn diagrams for completeness.